# Iterative Action On Each Row Of Table Matlab is so Slow

Tags: matlab

I have a variable Of Type table named AllBanks in MATLAB.I want to make the code faster. I've ran a loop to add new variables. code is as follows but it is pretty slow.

```
 for i2=1:size(AllBanks,1)

        AllBanks.SheetNameTrimmed(i2)= strrep(AllBanks.SheetName(i2),char(32),'');
        AllBanks.EngName(i2)={strcat(AllBanks.SheetName{i2} ,sprintf('%02d',AllBanks.RowNumber(i2)))};
        AllBanks.EngNameTrimmed(i2)={strcat(AllBanks.SheetNameTrimmed{i2} ,sprintf('%02d',AllBanks.RowNumber(i2)))};

    end
```

It has a Column named SheetName which is of type char,also a numeric column named Rownumber. 
A Sample Of Table is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your sample, I've composed a table in MATLAB:

```
SheetName = {'daraie ha';'motalebat';'bedehi ha';'daraie ha'};
RowNumber = [1; 9; 10; 20];

AllBanks = table(SheetName,RowNumber);
```

Using this table, your original code takes 0.007432 seconds. Let's try an alternative:

```
tic;
% first make the 'SheetNameTrimmed' column. Notice how you can do it
% outside the for loop
AllBanks.SheetNameTrimmed= strrep(AllBanks.SheetName,char(32),'');

% Next, generate a new cell array from RowNumber
tmp1 = cellstr(num2str(AllBanks.RowNumber,'%02d'));

% Concatenate SheetName and SheetNameTrimmed with tmp1.
EngName = strcat(AllBanks.SheetName,tmp1);
EngNameTrimmed = strcat(AllBanks.SheetNameTrimmed,tmp1);    

% Now simply declare two new columns from the new cell arrays
AllBanks.EngName = EngName;
AllBanks.EngNameTrimmed = EngNameTrimmed;
toc
```

This code takes 0.003829 seconds, about half the time as the original code.

For future reference, vectorizing your code will generally lead to improvements in speed. As a rule of thumb, avoid for loops if you can.

Comment: Great! But There is One Problem. my and your code does not generate exactly same output. your code puts extra spaces while concatenating.

Comment: @mahyar sefidgaran oops, you'll have to add something like a `strrep` call to `EngNameTrimmed` to remove the whitespace. I'll update the answer once I have a chance to rerun the code

Comment: @ Delyle : It's Somehow dangerous because sheet name column have values that have spaces which we do not want to remove,for example 'daraie ha'.

Comment: @ Delyle : It seems the problem is not concatenation but char function which adds white space

Comment: @mahyar sefidgaran do the sheet names always have the same number of characters? In your sample data they do

Comment: @mahyar sefidgaran I updated the code, and the result is now the same as your original script. The updated code will also be able to accommodate strings of arbitrary length in any column

Comment: WOW! You are genius! thanks a lot. Best wishes for you.